# How can I determine the last location of the subscriber for each day?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table:

| abonent | region_id | dttm |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7072110988 | 32722 | 2021-08-18 13:15 |
| 7072110988 | 32722 | 2021-08-18 14:00 |
| 7072110988 | 21534 | 2021-08-18 14:15 |
| 7072110988 | 32722 | 2021-08-19 09:00 |
| 7071107101 | 12533 | 2021-08-19 09:15 |
| 7071107101 | 32722 | 2021-08-19 09:27 |

Description of attributes:

1. abonent – subscriber's number;
2. region_id – id of the region where the subscriber is located;
3. dttm – the day and time of the call.

I need to determine the last location of the subscriber for each day.

Someone help please, I'm new to SQL(

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of tables into markup tables? See [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables) for how. You might find [tablesgenerator.com](//www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with helper as (select abonent, region_id, dttm,
                       row_number() over (partition by abonent, date(dttm) 
                                          order by dttm desc) as row_number
                from abonent_log)
select abonent, region_id, dttm 
from helper
where row_number = 1;
```

The window function `row_number()` helps to enumerate abonents inside of a group (`abonent, date(dttm)`).

Also, `date()` function is used inside of a `partition`-clause to group values by some date, not the full date-time value.

See the [demo](https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3yvg76k9z).

Answer (score 0):

Generate time series could solve the groupings and a MAX from the group should retrieve the last from the group.

```
 SELECT sq.lastdate ,sq.allregions,sq.allabonents, c.dttm lastdate, c.abonent lastabonent , c.region_id lastregion FROM 
    (SELECT MAX(dttm) lastdate, array_agg(b.region_id) allregions ,array_agg(b.abonent) allabonents , dateRange
    FROM generate_series(current_date - interval '1 year' , current_date , interval '1 day') daterange
    JOIN table AS b ON b.dttm >= daterange AND b.dttm <= daterange+interval'1 day' 
    ) AS sq 
    JOIN table AS c ON c.dttm = sq.lastdate
```