# Explain SQL request

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can anyone explain how does SQL request from this [How can I determine the last location of the subscriber for each day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75182289/how-can-i-determine-the-last-location-of-the-subscriber-for-each-day) answer (written by Albina) work?

I tried to understand it. Already have read about window-functions, but still can't keep the problem in mind.

I would be happy to read a detailed explanation, if it's possible.

P.S. I forced to ask a new question as long as my reputation lvl does not accept to ask in comment section in foreign posts.

Comment: A good approach to understanding such a query is to run the parts individually. First run the inner select (from the CTE) on its own and study the result. Then think about what happens if you apply a WHERE clause on that result

Answer (score 1):

```sql
with helper as (select abonent, region_id, dttm,
                       row_number() over (partition by abonent, date(dttm) 
                                          order by dttm desc) as row_number
                from abonent_log)
select abonent, region_id, dttm 
from helper
where row_number = 1;
```

Here CTE selects all rows from table `abonent_log` and adds ordering numbers to each row. Ordering happens within partitions, meaning for each different pair (`abonent`, date of `dttm`) ordering begins from start.

Later main query select from CTE only rows that where assigned number 1 wjile ordering.